# Game throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

So i am making a small game called dodge were rectangles fall from the "sky" and you have to do dodge them. As i ran the game this error message just popped up and i have no clue why. Also the screen just goes white whenever i run the program.

I cannot figure this out, Ive searched for hours in my code cant figure out why. Please Halp

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dodge.Enemy.move(Enemy.java:22)
    at dodge.Enemy.draw(Enemy.java:32)
    at dodge.EnemyManager.draw(EnemyManager.java:34)
    at dodge.Dodge.paint(Dodge.java:38)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5226)
    at
```

Sorry thats long. But here is my code.

Dodge.java

```
package dodge;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Dodge extends JPanel  implements KeyListener{

    private Player player;
    private Stage stage;

    private EnemyManager manager;

    public Dodge(){
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        stage = new Stage();
        player = new Player(this, 200, 200);
        manager = new EnemyManager(this, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        stage.draw(g);
        player.draw(g);
       manager.draw(g);
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }
 @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
          player.setXD(0);
          player.setYD(0);
   }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

   }

    public Stage getStage(){
        return stage;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
       int c = e.getKeyCode();
       if(c == KeyEvent.VK_W){

       }
       if(c ==KeyEvent.VK_A){
       player.setXD(-1);
       }
       if(c == KeyEvent.VK_S){

       }
       if(c ==KeyEvent.VK_D){
       player.setXD(1);
       }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Dodge the Rectangles");
        frame.add(new Dodge());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

EnemyManager.java

```
package dodge;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

public class EnemyManager {

    private int amount;
    private List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    private Dodge instance;

    public EnemyManager(Dodge instance, int a){
        this.amount = a;
        spawn();
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    private void spawn(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int ss = enemies.size();
        if(ss<amount){
            for(int i = 0; i < amount - ss; i++){
                enemies.add(new Enemy(instance, random.nextInt(778), 10));
            }
        }else if(ss>amount){
            for(int i = 0; i < ss - amount; i++){
                enemies.remove(i);
        }
    }
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        for(Enemy e : enemies) e.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Enemy.java

```
package dodge;

import java.awt.*;

public class Enemy extends Entity{

    private Rectangle hitbox;
    private int ix, iy;
    private boolean dead = false;
    private Dodge instance;

    public Enemy(Dodge instance, int x, int y){
        super(x, y);
        this.instance = instance;
        hitbox = new Rectangle (x, y, 32, 32);

        ix = 0;
        iy = 1;
    }

    private void move(){
        if(instance.getStage().isCollided(hitbox)){
            iy = 0;
            dead = true;
        }
        hitbox.x += ix;
        hitbox.y +=iy;
    }
    private boolean isDead() {return dead;}

     @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        move();
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(hitbox.x, hitbox.y, hitbox.width, hitbox.height);
    }

}
```

Entity.java

```
package dodge;

import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Entity {

    protected int x, y, w, h;
    protected boolean removed = false;

    public Entity(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

    }

    public int getX() {return x;}
    public int getY(){return y;}
    public int getW() {return w;}
    public int getH(){return h;}
}
```

Player.java

```
package dodge;

import java.awt.*;

public class Player extends Entity{

    private int xd, yd;
    private Dodge instance;
    private Rectangle hitbox;

    public Player(Dodge instance, int x , int y){
        super(x, y);
        this.instance = instance;
        w = 16; h = 16;

        hitbox = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        move();
        if(!instance.getStage().isCollided(hitbox)){
            yd = 1;

        }else yd = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(hitbox.x, hitbox.y, hitbox.width, hitbox.height);
    }

    private void move(){
        hitbox.x += xd;
        hitbox.y +=yd;

    }

    public void setXD(int value){
        xd = value;
    }

     public void setYD(int value){
        yd = value;

    }
}
```

Stage.java

```
package dodge;
import java.awt.*;
public class Stage {

    private Rectangle platform = new Rectangle(0, 540, 800, 100);

    public Stage(){
    }

    public boolean isCollided(Rectangle entity){
        return platform.intersects(entity);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(platform.x, platform.y, platform.width, platform.height);
    }

}
```

I hope that wasnt too long. Thanks

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which actually summarizes the problem. And yes, it was too long.

Comment: What have you tried? what do you think could be happening? This is a very good first approach to asking a question. Try to give as much info on *your analysis*, instead of as much info on *the problem* as you did here. Even if your analysis is way off, it's easier to explain why could you be having issues. Most of the time these issues are related to misunderstanding how frameworks work.

Answer (score 3):

Read the stacktrace. Either `Enemy.instance` or `Enemy.instance.getStage()` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> Also the screen just goes white whenever i run the program.

1. Don't override update() and paint(). That is old code used in AWT and is NOT the way custom painting is done in Swing. In Swing you simply override the paintComponent() method of the JPanel and don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.
2. Don't invoke repaint() in a painting method. That will cause an infinite loop. The is not the way to do animation. Use a Swing Timer or a separate Thread to schedule the animation.